# Xcode error - xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, ios-simulator

I am new to ios app development. I am trying to run the following command in terminal.

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace test.xcworkspace -scheme test -destination "platform:iOS,id:5E6F97EE-2CD8-4701-AC36-1A488CA646DF,OS:14.1,name:iPhone 11" -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
```

I am getting the following error

```
xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'
```

I tried different way as suggested in StackOverflow and git. But nothing worked for me.

these are the following commands I tried.

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace test.xcworkspace -scheme test -destination "platform:iOS,id:5E6F97EE-2CD8-4701-AC36-1A488CA646DF,OS:14.1,name:iPhone 11" -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO

xcodebuild clean build -workspace test.xcworkspace -scheme test -destination 'platform:iOS,id:5E6F97EE-2CD8-4701-AC36-1A488CA646DF,OS:14.1,name:iPhone 11' -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO

xcodebuild clean build -workspace test.xcworkspace -scheme test -destination platform:iOS,id:5E6F97EE-2CD8-4701-AC36-1A488CA646DF,OS:14.1,name:iPhone 11 -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `=` instead of `:` in destination like this:

```
'platform=iOS,id=5E6F97EE-2CD8-4701-AC36-1A488CA646DF,OS=14.1,name=iPhone 11'
```